# Best-responding to a stochastically higher distribution of bids

Tags: auctions, probability

In [Auction Theory](https://www.elsevier.com/books/auction-theory/krishna/978-0-12-374507-1), Krishna writes that:

> a bidder who faces a stochastically higher distribution of bids–in the
>   sense of reverse hazard rate dominance–will bid higher

(This follows the proof of proposition 4.4 in the section 'Weakness Leads to Aggression'.)

Supposedly, this is 'easy to see' - however, I am having trouble seeing it! I would be grateful if someone could explain why this is true.

My (unsuccessful) efforts so far:

If I bid $b$ when my valuation is $v$, then (under risk neutrality) my expected utility is

$$(v - b)F(b)$$

where $F(b)$ is the cumulative distribution function of all the bids apart from mine (and thus the probability that I win the auction).

Maximising my expected utility with respect to $b$, we obtain the first order condition

$$(v - b)f(b) - F(b) = 0$$

Which implies that

$$b = v - \frac{F(b)}{f(b)}$$

A distribution $G$ is stochastically higher than a distribution $F$ in the sense of reverse hazard rate dominance when, for every $b$

$$\frac{g(b)}{G(b)} > \frac{f(b)}{F(b)}$$

Now, if $f(b)/F(b)$ and $g(b)/G(b)$ do not depend on $b$, it is obvious from the first order condition that I will bid higher when facing a stochastically higher distribution of bids. However, it is not clear to me what happens in the general case where the 'hazard rates' may depend on $b$.

Many thanks in advance!

**Bonus question:** When my bids increase, will my new distribution of bids 'stochastically dominate' my old distribution (in the sense of the reverse hazard rate)?

Comment: I'm not sure if your first order conditions are correct. The expected profit is $(v - b)F(\beta^{-1}(x))$, where $b=\beta (x)$. You can further consider $\beta^{-1} = \phi$, therefore the expected profit can be rewritten as $(v - b)F(\phi (b))$.

Comment: Your distribution F is the distribution of the highest *valuation* (apart from my own). However, my distribution F is the distribution of the highest *bid* (apart from my own). Hence, both of our expressions are correct - we are just using different notation.

Comment: Is your last sentence correct? Do you mean to say when this does or does not depend on $v$ rather than when these functions depend on (b)?

Comment: No, I do mean $b$. If the hazard rate does not depend on $b$, then we have an explicit formula for the optimal bid. However, if the hazard rate does depend on $b$, we only have an equation which defines $b$ implicitly, which makes things harder.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sketch of an answer.

As noted in the question, the optimal $b$ must satisfy

$$b = v - \frac{F(b)}{f(b)}$$

Let us define the function $h(b) = v - F(b)/f(b)$. Our problem is to find the the fixed points of the function $h(b)$, i.e. the $b$ such that

$$b = h(b)$$

What can we say about $h(b)$? Assuming there is a unique optimal bid, it crosses the 45 degree line exactly once. Moreover, assuming that bids cannot be negative, i.e. $F(b) = 0$, it follows that $h(0) = v$. Thus, assuming that $v > 0$, the function $h(b)$ starts off above the 45 degree line.

Now, when the opponent bids are 'stochastically higher', the function $h(b)$ moves upwards in the sense that the 'new' function lies everywhere above $h(b)$. It thus seems reasonably clear that the unique fixed point must increase, though admittedly I lack a conclusive proof of this fact.

I am also unsure about the bonus question (whether my new bids seem stochastically higher in the sense of the reverse hazard rate).